# c# ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, process

Why is this

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
myProcess.UserName = username;
myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(myProcess);
```

working, but

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
myProcess.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
myProcess.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
myProcess.UserName = username;
myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(myProcess);
```

is not.

I wanted to use the second one because of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621943/1306186

I am constantly getting a file not found exception... Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Path is for example `@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleApplication2.exe"`

Comment: Did you print the result of `Path.GetFileName(path);` and `Path.GetDirectoryName(path);`? Are they correct?

Comment: put a breakpoint in your code and compare the values in the `ProcessStartInfo` instance and the second one. See what differs.

Comment: if you change `myProcess.UseShellExecute = true;` the both are working .

Comment: @Tudor: Yes I did. `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)->C:\Users\User\Desktop` and `Path.GetFileName(path)->ConsoleApplication2.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit is wrong

```
myProcess.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

this should be

```
myProcess.FileName = path;
```

Pass in `C:\SomeDir\SomeApp.exe` and the code you have will set the filename to `SomeApp.exe`, which it can't find. Count yourself lucky, there are circumstances where it could have (e.g. your app and the app you want to run being in the same folder), and then you would have possibly got a funny when deploying.

Comment: This is exactly the same as my first example which I already marked as 'working'... The constructur is doing nothing but setting the `FileName` attribute.

Comment: @Zulakis, and your point is? 2nd example didn't work because it couldn't locate ConsoleApplication2.exe. First example, (and the suggested corrections does) did because you told it ConsoleApplication2.exe is in the C:\Users\User\Desktop where it can find it. If this wasn't the answer you wanted change your question to give us a clue as to the one you did...

Comment: According to the linked post in my entry post doing so is wrong... `[QUOTE]I had my entire path and file name set in the filename attribute, instead, place your path under the 'Working Directory' property, leave the filename property just for the 'file name'. [/QUOTE]` ....

Comment: That's the working directory of the application you are trying to srart

Comment: That's a different issue. Your code sets ConsoleApplication2's working directory. If you wanted to use it to solve your problem, you'd need to set the working directory of the calling application to where ConsoleApplication2 is, and I definitely do not recommend doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `Path.GetFullPath()` instead of simply `Path.GetFileName()` since the constructor initializes the `FileName` with the full path when you use it with the string parameter.