# Installing MSU, but get error 'directory name invalid'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install a MSU file which is located on a shared drive:

```
if (([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major -lt 10) -and ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 3))
{
    $command = "`"" + "Z:\00 - FTA - General\12 - IT\Scripts\Win7 WMF5  KB3134760-x64.msu" + "`""
    $parameters = $command + " /quiet"
    $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters,$Username,$Password,"domainName" )
    $install.WaitForExit()
    $install.ExitCode
}
```

However I get the error message:

> Exception calling "Start" with "5" argument(s): "The directory name is invalid"
>       At line:8 char:5
>       +     $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameter ...
>       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Anyone here who knows what I'm doing wrong?
I also tried replacing the drive letter with the IP, but it yelds the same error message...

```
\\192.168.254.3\D$\office\00 - FTA - General\12 - IT\Scripts\Win7 WMF5  KB3134760-x64.msu
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990562/win32exception-the-directory-name-is-invalid)

Comment: Does the same error occur if you use Start-Process instead? Random thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've over complicated this task, you just need to use the Call Operator (`&`) to run `wusa` and pass it the path to the file along with the `quiet` and `norestart` options.

```
$msu = "\\192.168.254.3\D$\office\00 - FTA - General\12 - IT\Scripts\Win7 WMF5  KB3134760-x64.msu"

& wusa $msu /quiet /norestart
```